# Visual representations of groups (in their symmetric groups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, visualization

Given a group $G$, left and right multiplications establish the subgroups $\Theta:=\lbrace \theta_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ and $\Gamma:=\lbrace \gamma_a \mid a\in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, such that:

- $G \cong \Theta$;
- $G \cong \Gamma$;
- $\theta_a\gamma_b=\gamma_b\theta_a, \forall a,b \in G$ and then $\Theta\Gamma=\Gamma\Theta \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$;
- $Z(G) \cong \Theta \cap \Gamma$;
- $\Theta \unlhd \Theta\Gamma$ and $\Gamma \unlhd \Theta\Gamma$.

Besides, coniugacy establishes the subgroup $\Phi:=im_\varphi = \lbrace \varphi_{a} \mid a \in G\rbrace \le \operatorname{Aut}(G) \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$. It turns out that $ker_\varphi=Z(G)$, whence $\Phi \cong G/Z(G)$ (fundamental homomorphism theorem), and finally:

- $G$ abelian $\Leftrightarrow Z(G)=G \Leftrightarrow \Phi= \lbrace \iota_{\operatorname{Sym}(G)} \rbrace$;
- $G$ centerless ($Z(G)=\lbrace e \rbrace$) $\Leftrightarrow \Phi \cong G$.

REMARK. $\Phi$ is nothing else but *the group of inner automorphisms of $G$*, differently denoted by $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ or $\mathscr{I}(G)$.

**Proposition 0.** $\Phi \unlhd \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

*Proof.* $\forall a,b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, we get: $(\sigma^{-1}\varphi_a\sigma)(b)=\sigma^{-1}(\varphi_a(\sigma(b)))=\sigma^{-1}(a^{-1}\sigma(b)a)=$ $\sigma^{-1}(a^{-1})b\sigma^{-1}(a)$; call $\tau:=\sigma^{-1} \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, then $(\sigma^{-1}\varphi_a\sigma)(b)=\tau(a^{-1})b\tau(a)=\tau(a)^{-1}b\tau(a)=$ $\varphi_{\tau(a)}(b)$, so that $\sigma^{-1}\varphi_a\sigma=\varphi_{\sigma^{-1}(a)} \in \Phi$.

$\blacksquare$

REMARK. $\operatorname{Out}(G):=\operatorname{Aut}(G)/\Phi$ is *the (factor) group of outer automorphisms of $G$*.

**Proposition 1.** $\Phi \le \Theta\Gamma$.

*Proof.* By definition of $\varphi_a$, $\theta_b$ and $\gamma_c$, it is $\varphi_a=\theta_ {a^{-1}}\gamma_a$, and then $\Phi \subseteq \Theta\Gamma$.

$\blacksquare$

**Proposition 2.** $\Phi \cap \Theta = \Phi \cap \Gamma = \lbrace \iota_{\operatorname{Sym}(G)}\rbrace$.

*Proof.* $\varphi_a \in \Theta \Leftrightarrow \exists b \in G \mid \varphi_a = \theta_b \Leftrightarrow \varphi_a(c) = \theta_b(c), \forall c \in G \Leftrightarrow a^{-1}ca=bc, \forall c \in G \Rightarrow$ (take $c=a$) $a=ba \Rightarrow b=e \Rightarrow \varphi_a=\theta_e=\iota_{\operatorname{Sym}(G)}$.

Equivalently, $\theta_a$ is a homomorphism (and then an automorphism of $G$) iff $\theta_a(bc)=\theta_a(b)\theta_a(c)$ iff $abc=abac$ iff $a=e$ iff $\theta_a=\theta_e=\iota_{\operatorname{Sym}(G)}$.

$\blacksquare$

**Proposition 3.** $\Phi = \Theta\Gamma \cap \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

*Proof.* $\theta_a\gamma_b \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ iff $(\theta_a\gamma_b)(cd)=(\theta_a\gamma_b)(c)(\theta_a\gamma_b)(d)$ iff $acdb=acbadb$ iff $e=ba$ iff $\theta_a\gamma_b=\theta_{b^{-1}}\gamma_b$ iff $\theta_a\gamma_b \in \Phi$.

$\blacksquare$

It seems to me that Proposition 3 makes the wording "inner automorphisms" plausible: they are precisely the only automorphisms that lie *inside* the "widest border of $G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$", namely $\Theta\Gamma$.

All what above, has brought me to envisage the following pictures of "limit" and "in between" situations:

---

[image]

[image]

### [image]

I haven't got a specific question to ask, but rather if you can see some other "nice feature" I could add, or amend, on the picture.

Comment: Based on the use of left and right multiplication alone, I guess semigroup theory might help here.

Comment: Use, for example, `$\operatorname{Sym}$` for $\operatorname{Sym}$.

Comment: I think this is a high quality question :)

Comment: Something seems wrong with your "G not abelian" picture. You have Inn(G) sitting inside $\Theta \cap \Gamma$ which isn't right.

Comment: @Ted: so I have to prove that $\Theta \ne \Gamma \Rightarrow Inn(G) \cap (\Theta \cap \Gamma) \ne Inn(G)$, isn't it? I'll amend soon the picture, thanks! Anyway, this is exactly the way I wished the pictures to help for getting (known) algebric results.

Comment: @Ted: upon your hint, I have realized that a much stronger condition than I guessed (<<...$Inn(G)$ has some exceeding out of $\Theta \cap \Gamma$...>>) does hold, namely what's now in Proposition 2: $Inn(G)$ shares with $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ just the unit. Pictures have changed their "topology" accordingly.

Comment: In the abelian situation, if $|G|>2$, it is never the case that $\operatorname{Aut}(G) = \operatorname{Inn}(G)$, as appears to be depicted in the first picture. Abelian groups of order $>2$ always have nontrivial automorphisms, but no nontrivial inner automorphisms.

Comment: Also, the second and third diagrams are confusing me. The question shows you realize that $\Theta\cap \operatorname{Aut}(G) = id.$ and $\Gamma\cap \operatorname{Aut}(G) = id.$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cap \Phi$, but the diagrams seem to me to make it appear that $\Phi$ is not contained in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and meanwhile $\Phi$ contains $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$, whereas it meets them only trivially as you show in proposition 2.

Comment: Incidentally, what you are calling "maximally nonabelian" is ordinarily called *centerless*. There are other competing possible meanings for "maximally nonabelian", for example *perfect:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group. Also, a group can be centerless but pretty close to being abelian in other respects, for example $S_3$ is centerless even though it is solvable height 2 and actually metacyclic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacyclic_group).

Comment: I've tried to make the situation clearer by using arrows: $\Phi$ is meant to be the region where the two arrows overlap.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the green arrow means. I thought it was labeling $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$. (Also, tbh, since the diagrams have the appearance of venn diagrams, it took me a while to figure out that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\setminus id.$ was supposed to be an annulus. That's when I noticed the arrows.)

Comment: Green arrow = span of $\Theta\Gamma$ region; Purple arrow = span of $Aut(G) \setminus \lbrace \iota \rbrace$ region. Anyway, I'll try to review thoroughly the visual part.

Comment: Overlap of the two spans = $Inn(G) \setminus \lbrace \iota \rbrace$

Comment: Incidentally, since the elements of $\Phi$ are the only automorphisms _inside_  the "widest border of $G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$", namely $\Theta\Gamma$, it make sense to call them the "inner automorphisms".