# How does a group look like in its symmetric group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

(This may look similar to past questions of mine, but actually adds something and goes more straight to the point.)

Let $G$ be a (possibly infinite) group. Left and right multiplications establish the subgroups $\Theta:=\lbrace \theta_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ and $\Gamma:=\lbrace \gamma_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, such that:

- $G \cong \Theta$ and $G \cong \Gamma$;
- $\theta_a\gamma_b=\gamma_b\theta_a, \forall a,b \in G \Rightarrow \Theta\Gamma=\Gamma\Theta \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$;
- $\Theta \unlhd \Theta\Gamma$ and $\Gamma\unlhd \Theta\Gamma$;
- $Z(G) \cong \Theta \cap \Gamma$;
- $\operatorname{Inn}(G)= \Theta\Gamma \cap \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Moreover, unless I'm mistaken, I have come to: $$Z(\Theta\Gamma)=\lbrace \theta_a\gamma_b \mid \theta_{[a,c]}=\gamma_{[b,d]}, \forall c,d \in G\rbrace \tag 1$$ where $[a,b]$ stands for the commutator of $a$ e $b$. My questions are:

1. Is $(1)$ correct?
2. Where is $Z(\Theta\Gamma)$ placed in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ with respect to the other structures $(\Theta$, $\Gamma$, $\Theta \cap \Gamma$, $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, $\operatorname{Aut}(G))$?
3. Where is $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ placed in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ with respect to the other structures $(\Theta$, $\Gamma$, $\Theta\Gamma$, $\Theta \cap \Gamma$, $\operatorname{Inn}(G))$?

Of course, also partial answers 1+2 and 1+3 will be perfectly fine.

---

### Addendum

Actually, I have already shared [some ideas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097209/visual-representations-of-groups-in-their-symmetric-groups) about the "positions" of these subgroups in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. Here, I just wanted to include in the picture $Z(\Theta\Gamma)$ (that I hadn't realized to equal $\Theta \cap \Gamma$, so forget about Q2) and $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$. Although it is trivially $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G)) \cap \Theta = Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G)) \cap \Gamma = \lbrace \iota \rbrace$, it seems to me that still makes sense to ask about $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G)) \cap \operatorname{Inn}(G)$. Here's my attempt.

Let $\varphi \colon G \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ be defined by $\varphi_a(g):=a^{-1}ga$. Then $\Phi:= \operatorname{im} \varphi=\operatorname{Inn}(G)$.

We get:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi_a \in Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G)) &\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a\sigma=\sigma\varphi_a, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (\varphi_a\sigma)(b)=(\sigma\varphi_a)(b), \forall b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a(\sigma(b))=\sigma(\varphi_a(b)), \forall b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a(\sigma(b))=\sigma(a^{-1}ba), \forall b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a(\sigma(b))=\sigma(a^{-1})\sigma(b)\sigma(a), \forall b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a(\sigma(b))=\sigma(a)^{-1}\sigma(b)\sigma(a), \forall b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a(\sigma(b))=\varphi_{\sigma(a)}(\sigma(b)), \forall b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (\varphi_a\sigma)(b)=(\varphi_{\sigma(a)}\sigma)(b), \forall b \in G, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a\sigma=\varphi_{\sigma(a)}\sigma, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \varphi_a=\varphi_{\sigma(a)}, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \sigma(a) \in (\operatorname{ker}\varphi)a, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
&\Leftrightarrow a \in K
\end{alignat}

where: $$ K:= \lbrace a \in G \mid \sigma(a) \in (\operatorname{ker}\varphi)a, \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \rbrace$$

It is $K \le G$; in fact, being $\operatorname{ker}\varphi \unlhd G$:

- $a,b \in K \Rightarrow \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G), (\sigma(a) \in (\operatorname{ker}\varphi)a) \wedge (\sigma(b) \in (\operatorname{ker}\varphi)b) \Rightarrow \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G), \sigma(a)\sigma(b)=\sigma(ab) \in (\operatorname{ker}\varphi)a(\operatorname{ker}\varphi)b=(\operatorname{ker} \varphi)(ab) \Rightarrow ab \in K$
- $a \in K \Rightarrow \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G), \sigma(a) \in (\operatorname{ker} \varphi)a \Rightarrow \forall \sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G), \sigma(a)^{-1}=\sigma(a^{-1}) \in a^{-1}(\operatorname{ker} \varphi)=(\operatorname{ker}\varphi)a^{-1} \Rightarrow a^{-1} \in K$

Then, finally, I'd be led to conclude that: $$Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G)) \cap \operatorname{Inn}(G)=\varphi_K \tag 2$$

but I can't figure out what $K$ "precisely" is (provided that $(2)$ really holds).

Comment: $Z(\Theta\Gamma)$ is equal to $\Theta\cap\Gamma$ (which is isomorphic to $Z(G)$, as you wrote).

Comment: I don't see any reason why $Z(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$ could be described in terms of the given subgroups.

Comment: I was somehow led to think that some relationship existed by the fact that $\operatorname{Inn}(G)=\Theta\Gamma \cap \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: The latter equality says that given $\Theta\Lambda$, $Aut(G)$ determines $Inn(G)$. But not vice versa.

Comment: Edited with my attempt.